# ISP "hide" packet trace route

Tags: networking

Yesterday , i've discovered changes in my network , our ISP hides trace route .

ie :

```
traceroute to 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  192.168.88.1 (192.168.55.1)  0.256 ms  0.251 ms  0.314 ms
 2  google-public-dns-a.google.com (8.8.8.8)  102.336 ms  102.477 ms  114.432 ms
```

Now i can't verify packets route ,or check ISP fault . Is there any chance to discover where packets are sent ?

it's normal ISP behaving nowadays ?

Comment: `8.8.8.8` is an anycast address. Could you try looking up a unicast address of that DNS server. You can use `dig -t aaaa mydnsv6.kasperd.net @8.8.8.8` to look it up. And what does the route look like if you specify a unicast address rather than an anycast address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now i can't verify packets route, or check ISP fault.

Yes.

> Is there any chance to discover where packets are sent ?

No, not without access to the ISPs systems (or access to the system killing your TTL information, like firewalls sometimes do). The routers on the way *do* have to increment the TTL of ICMP packets, if the don't do that, they behave completely transparent - just like switches (which you kannot detect by traceroute).

> it's normal ISP behaving nowadays ?

No, and it shouldn't be. The header TTL is vital for the network, as it kills paket that travel for too long. Thats the same for all protocol types, including ICMP.